# how can I ignore sanitization errors/warnings with angular 2.0.0?

Tags: angular

Before RC6 i did this way:

```
    import { Injectable, provide, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
    import { DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Injectable()
    export class NoSanitizationService {
      sanitize(ctx: SecurityContext, value: any): string {
        return value;
      }
    }

    export const NO_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS: any[] = [
      provide(DomSanitizationService, { useClass:         NoSanitizationService }),
    ];
```

How can I do it with new angular release 2.0.0 ? Because I can't use `provide` function.

Comment: was it working with RC6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DomSanitizationService**  was renamed to **DomSanitizer**.

```
import { Injectable, provide, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class NoSanitizationService {
  sanitize(ctx: SecurityContext, value: any): string {
    return value;
  }
}

export const NO_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS: any[] = [
  {provide:DomSanitizer, useClass:NoSanitizationService },  //<----changed this line as well
];
```

---

```
import {NO_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS} from 'valid path';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [NO_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS],                //<----here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not import **provide** and write it like this :

```
export const NO_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS: any[] = [
    { provide: DomSanitizationService, useClass: NoSanitizationService }
];
```

Comment: Its DomSanitizer, not DomSanitizationService